# frameset tag is working while I have imported strict.dtd

Tags: html, frameset

Problem:  tag is working while I have imported  statement as a firstline in html page.

Problem Description :- I have created a page TestingDoctype.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Testing DOCTYPE</title>
        </head>
        <frameset >
            <frame src="a.htm"/>
        </frameset>
         <frameset >
            <frame src="b.htm"/>
        </frameset>
            <frameset >
            <frame src="c.htm"/>
        </frameset>
            <frameset >
            <frame src="d.htm"/>
        </frameset>
  </html>
```

I have used  tag with strict dtd and still browser parsed it and display the page.

I tried to search example on google but I am not getting any example which can clear the difference among these dtd.
            Please provide some links so that I can clear the concept of dtd files.

I will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers pay no attention to DTDs. They are useful (in the context of HTML) for very little other then performing validation. (Using [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/) is a very good idea).

(Browsers do pay attention to Doctypes, but only as magic strings that switch between standards/almost standards/quirks parsing/rendering modes.)

Comment: If it is context of HTML then please tell me the reason whey frameset is working on strict.dtd import statement.

Comment: See the very first sentence of this answer. If the DTD is ignored, how could the choice of DTD stop framesets working?

Comment: I understand your concern but please clear one thing that what are the conditions when html doesn't understand dtd line. Because I am still not getting why my page is running with frameset tag while I am importing strict.dtd statement. (If it is in context of html then html should understand the dtd tag and it shouldn't display frameset tag)  -

Please clear the confusion. I would be highly obliged.

Comment: HTML doesn't understand the Doctype ever. DTD capable parsers do understand the Doctype. Browsers do not use DTD capable parsers (they use parsers with hardcoded rules for HTML). (Browsers do misunderstand it, deliberately, in order to switch between standards mode and quirks mode).. DTD based SGML validators do. A few other tools do.